# How do I change a Button font after it's added to a ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, android-fonts, android-typeface

Given a `Button` created at runtime:

```
Button button = Button(context)
```

The way to set a custom typeface is:

```
button.setTypeface(myTypeface)
```

However I find it only works *before* I add it to a `ViewGroup` and not *after*.

I've also tried:

```
button.setTypeface(myTypeface, myStyle)
```

but it didn't work either. I need to change my `Button` font dynamically. I've tried `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` but the font never changes.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:- you can subclass the Button class with your custom font and use it instead of button.**

```
public class MyButton extends AppCompatButton {

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, like I said, my problem is that I can't change it *after* I add it to the ViewGroup